# different code but the output does not change when i test on a device

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native-base

Hello i am beginner in react native, and i followed all the guides to use react native with native base, but whenever i test the application using the sample codes below, i still get

> " welcome to React Native, to get started, edit index.android.js"

as you can see code and output do not match, any idea on how to solve this?

```
 import {Container, Content, Button, Icon} from 'native-base';
import React, {Component} from 'react-native';
​
export default class IconButtonExample extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            
                
                    
                        
                        Home
```

`<Button success iconRight>
                    Next
                    <Icon name="ios-arrow-forward" />
                </Button>

                <Button info>
                    Previous
                    <Icon name="ios-arrow-back" />
                </Button>

                <Button warning>
                    <Icon name="ios-star" />
                </Button>

                <Button danger>
                    <Icon name="ios-close-circle" />
                </Button>

                <Button style={{backgroundColor: '#384850'}} >
                    <Icon name="ios-search" style={{color: '#00c497'}}/>
                </Button>
            </Content>
        </Container>
    );
}`

}

Comment: What do you have inside `index.android.js`?

Comment: the code above, but the app doesn't update it's view whenever i build by running "react-native run-android"

Comment: if that's the case I don't see where you are using the app registry: `AppRegistry.registerComponent`

Comment: The code you've shown isn't valid (unless SO mangled it), it's missing some start tags and text tags.  Is the packager crashing or the build failing?  That could cause the display not to update.

Comment: whatever sample code i put inside 'index.android.js' doesn't  update the view on the device and nothing fails.

Comment: I  am using native base

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the code you posted above inside the main file named index.android.js

you need to restart your emulator and re-bundle the application

You can see here the default folder structure for react native projects.

[image]

[or read about it](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/organizing-a-react-native-project-9514dfadaa0)